# Calling HTTP API instead of database queries with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, activerecord

We have a system of two servers. One of them provides HTTP API, other calls it.

I wonder whether the API calling module could be in some way integrated with ActiveRecord to make calls to other server's entities like sending database queries.

I suppose that a custom database provider should be written to achieve the goal.

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it worth efforts?

Comment: It's not exactling what you are describing, but activeresource is a way to use REST API as if it was models - https://github.com/rails/activeresource

Answer (score 2):

1. You can do this with [Active Resource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource)
2. I prefer the use of ActiveRecord with DB access any time. It is more powerful. But if you only have that API you'll have to go Active Resource.

My advise: Give it a try. But don't stick to it in case you land in some corner.

Comment: I came back Rails after thousand years and discovering features like this is pleasing and brings back lot of good memories.